# Convert string into array in Perl

Tags: perl, multiline

I have a text file with data like this:

```
#addr_1     data_1        data_2       exp_data_1    exp_data_2    type          check_type    int_flag   
0xfec00000  0x12131415    0x22232425   0x12131415    0x22232425    movr_sstw     0x00000001    0x00       
0xfee00000  0x11234315    0x21234525   0x12734515    0x73333335    mov5_sth      0x00000002    0x1f
```

And I want to spilt it to store in array and I use this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $file_input = "./log_ex_7/input_data.txt";
my $file_output = "./output_data.txt";
open (FILE_INPUT,"<$file_input") || die ("Can not open");
foreach my $string (<FILE_INPUT>) {
    my @array = "";
    chomp ($string);
    if ($string !~ /#/) {
        my @slipt_string = split(/\s+/,$string);
        foreach my $i (@slipt_string) {
            push (@array,"$i ");
        }
        print ("$slipt_string[7]\n");
    }
}
```

But when I printed 1 element of the array its will print 2 values, how can I just print 1 of them ?:

```
0x00
0x1f
```

And I want to fill data in to the same label in this template

```
#############################################################  
  mov   0xc0ca0000 + 0x<stt>, r29  
#############################################################  
  movl    Handler, EXCEPTION_BASE_REG  
# Enable setting       
  mov     0x00000001, r5  
  mov     0x0000000c, r2  
  mov     <addr_1>, r30  
  mov     0x00000000, r8  
  mov     0x00000010, r26
  mov     <data_1>, r13 
  mov     <data_2>, r14 
  movl    brk_return_<stt>, r24  
  movl    cause_brk_<type>, r25  
  movl    PC_brk_<type>_inst1, r6
  movl    PC_brk_<type>_inst2, r7

  mov     <check_type>, r28  
  
  mov     0xbeefbeef, r12         # initial mem  
  st.w    r12,  0x0[r30]  
    
  mov     <int_flag>, r22               # initial flag  
  LDSR    (r22, PSW)  
  
  dbtrap  
  jr      Fail  
  
brk_return_<stt>:  
  mov     <exp_data_1>, r12 
  cmp     r12, r13  
  bne     Fail  
    
  mov     <exp_data_2>, r12 
  cmp     r12, r14  
  bne     Fail  
    
  ld.w    0x0[r30], r12  
  mov     0xbeefbeef, r13  
  cmp     r12, r13  
  bne     Fail
```

Also that I have solve the problem but I think it not optimize:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $first = "./log_ex_7/input_data.txt";
my $full = "./output_data.txt";
my $temp = "./log_ex_7/template.txt";
open (FILE_INPUT,"<$first") || die ("Can not open");
foreach my $string (<FILE_INPUT>) {
  chomp ($string);
  if ($string !~ /#/) {
    my @slipt_string = split (/\s+/,$string);
   my $temo = 0;
   foreach my $i (@slipt_string)
   {  
     push (@array,"$i");
   }
  }
}
close (FILE_INPUT);
my $length_string = @array;
open (FILE_OUT,  ">$full")   || die ("Can not open $full file");
close (FILE_OUT);
$llength_array = @array;
$llength_array /= 8;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $llength_array; $i++){
 open (FILE_OUT,">>$full") || die ("Can not open");
 open (FORMAT,"<$temp") || die ("Can not open this $$temp file");
foreach my $line (<FORMAT>){
      my $count_data = 0;  #we will use this variable to config data in array
      if ($i != 0) {
      $count_data = 8*$i;
      }

      chomp ($line);
      if ($line !~ /<*>/){
         print FILE_OUT ("$line\n");  
      }
      open (FILE_OUT,  ">>$full")   || die ("Can not open");
      if ($line =~ /<data_1>/){
          
         my $new = replace_string ("<data_1>",1+$count_data,$line,@array);
         print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
      }
     if ($line =~ /<addr_1>/){
       my $new = replace_string ("<addr_1>",0+$count_data,$line,@array);
        
        print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");

     }
     if ($line =~ /<stt>/){
         $num = $i + 1;
         $line =~ s/<stt>/$num/;       
         print FILE_OUT ("$line\n");
     }
     if ($line =~ /<data_2>/){
        my $new = replace_string("<data_2>",2+$count_data,$line,@array);
        print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
     }
     if ($line =~ /<type>/) {
        my $new = replace_string ("<type>",5+$count_data,$line,@array);
        print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
     }
     if ($line =~ /<check_type>/) {
         my $new= replace_string ("<check_type>",6+$count_data,$line,@array);
         print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
     }
     if ($line =~ /<int_flag>/) {
         my $new = replace_string ("<int_flag>",7+$count_data,$line,@array);
         print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");    
     }
      if ($line =~ /<exp_data_1>/) {
         my $new = replace_string ("<exp_data_1>",3+$count_data,$line,@array);
         print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
     }
       if ($line =~ /<exp_data_2>/) {
         my $new = replace_string ("<exp_data_2>",4+$count_data,$line,@array);
         print FILE_OUT ("$new\n");
     }
}
 close (FILE_OUT);
}
sub replace_string {
    my ($find_string, $count_data, $line, @array) = @_;
    $new = $line;
    $new =~s/$find_string/$array[$count_data]/;
    return $new;
}
close (FILE_OUT);
close (FORMAT);
system ("cat $full");
```

Comment: You have two lines of input. The loop will run twice and print two values. What was your expected output?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you just want to stop after printing the first line? If so, you can use the `last` statement

Comment: Hi, my bad is printed result when it still in loop, so I have taken it out loop. I have updated my code on post. Thanks for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output something at the end of each loop, so you get one line of output for each non-comment input line.

Here's what you have, but in a bit more idiomatic Perl so you don't have to do so much work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;
use warnings;

my @array;
foreach my $string (<DATA>) {
    next if $string =~ /^\s*#/;
    chomp $string;
    my @slipt_string = split /\s+/, $string;
    push @array, map { "$_ " } @slipt_string;
    say $slipt_string[7];
}


__DATA__
#addr_1     data_1        data_2       exp_data_1    exp_data_2    type          check_type    int_flag   
0xfec00000  0x12131415    0x22232425   0x12131415    0x22232425    movr_sstw     0x00000001    0x00       
0xfee00000  0x11234315    0x21234525   0x12734515    0x73333335    mov5_sth      0x00000002    0x1f
```

If you can say more about what you want the output to be, I might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advise, I have solve the problem. In my case, I want to fill the data likes addr_1 (values is 0xfec00000)- into another file have a label <addr_1>
  `# Enable setting       
  mov     0x00000001, r5  
  mov     0x0000000c, r2  
  mov     <addr_1>, r30  
   `